# 'logger_name' missing when enabling cors in my python app using flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-cors

I'm trying to get CORS working. A workaround works, however not on all api's. So I would like to have the regular way of working working. Which is now having me stuck here already for a while. I tried initializing CORS like this:

```
flask_app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(flask_app)
```

Which gives me the following error:

`return logging.getLogger("%s.cors" % app.logger_name)  AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'logger_name'`

The complete error is:

```
2021-12-18 16:30:57 default[20211218t172924]  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker      worker.init_process()    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process      self.load_wsgi()    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi      self.callable = self.load()    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load      return self.load_wsgiapp()    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 412, in import_app      app = app(*args, **kwargs)    
File "/workspace/app.py", line 38, in get_flask_app      CORS(flask_app)    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 59, in __init__      self.init_app(app, **kwargs)    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 81, in init_app      getLogger(app).info("Configuring CORS with resources: %s", resources_human)    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_cors/core.py", line 356, in getLogger      
return logging.getLogger("%s.cors" % app.logger_name)  AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'logger_name'
```

When I remove the CORS(flask_app), everything is fine. Except for the CORS issues I would like to fix.

This is my complete app.py:

```
# flask packages
from flask import Flask, request, app
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
import logging


# local packages
from api.routes import create_routes

# external packages
import os

# default mongodb configuration
default_config = {'MONGODB_SETTINGS': {
                    'db': '(....)',
                    'host': '(....)',
                    'port': 27017,
                    'username': 'admin',
                    'password': 'password',
                    'authentication_source': 'admin'},
                    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': '(...)'}


def get_flask_app(config: dict = None) -> app.Flask:
    """
    Initializes Flask app with given configuration.
    Main entry point for wsgi (gunicorn) server.
    :param config: Configuration dictionary
    :return: app
    """
    # init flask
    logging.getLogger('flask_cors').level = logging.DEBUG

    flask_app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(flask_app)

    # configure app
    config = default_config if config is None else config
    flask_app.config.update(config)

    # load config variables
    if 'MONGODB_URI' in os.environ:
        flask_app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {'host': os.environ['MONGODB_URI'],
                                                'retryWrites': False}
    if 'JWT_SECRET_KEY' in os.environ:
        flask_app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ['JWT_SECRET_KEY']

    # init api and routes
    api = Api(app=flask_app)
    create_routes(api=api)

    # init mongoengine
    db = MongoEngine(app=flask_app)

    # init jwt manager
    jwt = JWTManager(app=flask_app)

    return flask_app





if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Main entry point when run in stand-alone mode.
    app = get_flask_app()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Using Google Cloud Platform. Could this be the key to my issue? My app.yaml is:

```
runtime: python38
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT 'app:get_flask_app()'
```

I will try to see what happens locally, maybe it's solvable easier here. Thinking about when re-typing the question here.

Already updated my Flask-Cors (flask-cors). Tried a lot of things, nothing worked, hence this question.

Help is much appreciated / thanks!!

Comment: Can you format that traceback with line breaks so it's readable by mortals…?

Comment: Hey, of course! Edited it, hope it's more readable like this. In case more info is wanted, please mention, happy to change/add anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this part:

```
Flask.logger_name = "listlogger"
```

Ultimately solved it for me. Now it was able to find logger_name. That listlogger is just a random name.

I added it right before opening the app + CORS(app):

```
    Flask.logger_name = "listlogger"
    flask_app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(flask_app)
```